# Installing ubuntu but keep my old data

Tags: 14.04

Currently I have windows7. I have only one partition , Local Disk (C:) used space: 448gb and free space 482gb, File system NTFS. Its possible to install Ubuntu but to keep all my data I don't wana lose the data.

Comment: First rule of not losing data: backup. Second rule of not losing data: Backup. Third rule of not losing data: BACKUP. When you install Ubuntu choose the option to install "side by side" with Windows. The installation will do the rest. See [How do I install Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Just shorten your partition, create a new one, and move your data there.
Or if you want to keep Windows 7 (which I recomend you, at lest a week till Ubuntu works fine), just don't erase the windows partition while installing Ubuntu.

While installing, create 2 partitions: 1 ext4 for Ubuntu, and 1 swap (with aproximately the half of your RAM). It's very important that you select manual partitioning or something like that, in the Ubuntu installation.

Your disk should be for example like this:

```
400 GB Windwos 7
500 GB Your DATA
8 GB (half of your RAM) SWAP
92 (the rest) EXT4 (UBUNTU)
```

Comment: The "manual partitioning" option is called "Do something else". But before trying that, follow the three rules of @user68186 above.

Comment: What do you mean by swap partition?I have 4gb ram.I have like 100gb and my backup is only like 40gb

Comment: SWAP partition is something Ubuntu needs for working fine, and is a type if partition that you don't put your data. SWAP is the formatting type. In the Ubuntu installation let's you do that.

Comment: Ok thanks I will do as you said.Btw only 92 gb for ubuntu isnt to less?I wana install ubuntu 64bit

Comment: My whole Ubuntu OS runs in about 6 Gb of storage, excluding the /home folder which contains my user data.

Comment: Just be careful, because if you put 6GB of storage to Ubuntu, when you install something, maybe you can't because there is no free space.